# How can I by default have all text selected in my lineEdit?

Tags: pyqt

I'd like to be able to have all text highlighted in my lineEdit. However, the default selectAll() doesn't seem to do so.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from gui import Ui_Form

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("Type something here!")
        self.ui.lineEdit.selectAll()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.ui.textEdit.clear)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.add_entry)

    def add_entry(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.selectAll()
        self.ui.lineEdit.cut()
        self.ui.textEdit.append("")
        self.ui.textEdit.paste()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to select the text on the lineEdit in the default constructor; however, it doesn't. Any reason for this? What should I be doing instead to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement [`placeholderText`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop)?

Comment: @Avaris Yes! That was it, except it is setPlaceholderText(str)